# NServiceBus: Subscribe to AWS Textract event via SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, nservicebus

As the subject states: I'm using Amazon Textract to detect text on scanned documents. When Textract is done, it fires of a notification via SNS and the SQS queue subscribes to the notification.

I can reveive the "all done" event with the `AmazonSQSClient` but since the rest of the solution is built on top of NServiceBus I want to handle the native AWS events via NServiceBus as well.

How do I tell the `SqsTransport` to subscribe to a single, already existing SQS queue? I don't want nsb to create new queues and I don't intend to send messages via this queue. This endpoint is meant to be "receive only".

---

**UPDATE**

My problem is not "how do I get a native AWS event off the wire" but "how do I configure NSB to use my existing queue instead of creating its own".

**UPDATE2**
Turns out my problems is not *only* how to configure nsb. Getting the native AWS event off the wire is another obstacle that the documentation on native integration does not completely solve.

Answer (score 4):

By default, NServiceBus translates the endpoint name into the queue name. So if your endpoint name is, for example, `Sales.OrderProcessing` this will be translated to `Sales-OrderProcessing` by the Amazon SQS transport to make it compatible with the transport specific "restrictions".

It is possible to decouple the endpoint name from the queue name by overriding the local address of the endpoint

```cs
endpointConfiguration.OverrideLocalAddress("someothername");
```

https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/endpoints/specify-endpoint-name

Comment: Playing with the QueueNameGenerator in addition to overriding the local endpoint name gets me a little bit further but NSB keeps asking for additional queues. Error queue, delayed delivery queue, [...]. This should be a simple receive-only endpoint. Is there any way to prevent the usage of additional queues and just listen to the one that is already there?

Comment: @SebastianWeber The native delayed delivery cannot be disabled currently, unfortunately. The error queue is required to know where to move failed messages to.

There is a feature request that tracks making unrestricted delayed delivery optional https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS/issues/2161

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?
You will have to do the native to NSB consuming:
https://docs.particular.net/transports/sqs/native-integration

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your tip. Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I expected to have to use the native integration. But I'm missing the first step "how do I configure NSB to use an existing queue whose naming is not following the NSB naming conventions".

Answer (score 0):

While @DanielMarbach's answer helped it did not solve all the problems.
I had to set a custom `QueueNameGenerator` on the transport to fit my existing queues.

The validation of the timeout settings for the delayed message queue (which I honestly neither need nor want in my specific case) were rather hard to figure out because the validation inside NSB does not really fit the error message. `Delay is 00:01:00 but must be less than 00:15:00`... eh, what?! I had to set the timeout to the maximum of 15 minutes that SQS allows me.

The harder obstacle was that the `SqsTransport` (specifically the `InputQueuePump`) requires the `MessageTypeFullName` as part of the `MessageAttributes` of the native AWS message (or at least I could not find another way through the maze of message intake that worked with the notifications I get from Textract).
I tried a custom `Behavior` but could not find a stage early enough in the pipeline to work for me. I tried to customize the deserialization into `TransportMessage` but the message pump uses an internal `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` instance that does not care about settings or customizations of the global message serialization.
What I ended up doing was to write a decorator for the `IAmazonSqs` client the transport uses and intercept the `ReceiveMessageAsync` method. Since I only plan to use SQS for these notifications it was as simple as adding the AQTN of the message as a `MessageAttribute` of the received message.
Long story short: It is a much more involved process than I hoped but now I can hook up to the Textract notifications via NSB.

Comment: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS/releases/tag/5.7.2 and https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS/releases/tag/6.1.0 did improve the story slightly when it comes to native integration scenarios but there are still some hurdles as you rightfully pointed out. We captured some of them in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS/issues/1454